# What is the difference between Freidman mse and mse?

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics

I'm looking into a `GradientBoostingClassifier` in `sklearn`. Then, I found there are 3 kind of criterion. Friedman mse, mse, mae.
the descriptions provided by `sklearn` are:

> The function to measure the quality of a split. Supported criteria are “friedman_mse” for the mean squared error with improvement score by Friedman, “mse” for mean squared error, and “mae” for the mean absolute error. The default value of “friedman_mse” is generally the best as it can provide a better approximation in some cases.

I can't understand what is different?
Who's gonna let me know?

thanks!

Comment: You may find the answer to your question in formula (35) in Friedman's original Gradient Boosting paper or check out `FriedmanMSE` definition in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx)

Comment: Not a *coding* question, hence arguably off-topic here - better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I've provided a full answer in [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/66062/what-is-the-difference-between-freidman-mse-and-mse/66063#66063) link due to the convenience of writing TeX. However, it resumes in the fact that this splitting criterion allow us to take the decision not only on how close we're to the desired outcome (which is what MSE does), but also based on the probabilities of the desired k-class that we're going to find in the region l or in the region r (by considering a global weight w1*w2 / (w1 + w2)). I strongly recommend you to check the above link for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

According to the scikit-learn source code, the main difference between these two criteria is the `impurity-improvement` method. The MSE / FriedmanMSE criterion calculates an impurity of the current node and tries to reduce (improve) it, The smaller the impurity the better.

Mean squared error impurity criterion.

```py
MSE = sum_square_of_left / w_l + sum_square_of_right / w_r
```

[source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0e9d298be351eda7eb7302d6e673b097ae79831/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx#L926-L927)

On the other side FriedmanMSE impurity criterion use following to improve purity:

```py
diff = w_r * total_left_sum - w_l * total_rigth_sum
improvement = diff**2 / (w_r * w_l)
```

> Note: w_r (`right`) is for total `left` sum and visa versa.

you can simplify the following equations with the better notation, which was provided in Friedman published [paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ejhf/ftp/trebst.pdf) itself (eq. 35).
which says

improvement = (w_l * w_r) / (w_l + w_r) * (mean_left - mean_right) ^ 2

> Which `w_l`, `w_r` are the corresponding sum of weights for respective left or right part.

[source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f0e9d298be351eda7eb7302d6e673b097ae79831/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx#L1312)

For assigning meaning to `left` and `right` keywords, imagine the whole system in an array (e.g samples[start: end]), so for example `left` means the left elements of the current node.